# Problems opening an endpoint for the front-end to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sqlite3

As said in the title, I'm writing a aplication in Node.Js and I need it to return a JSON (or at least console.log() the data, I can figure out the rest) I it seems like the URL doesn't exist

BACKEND CODE

```
app.get("/ranking",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("ranking");
})

app.get("registros",()=>{
    db.all("SELECT * FROM resultados", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log(rows);
        return rows;
    });
})
```

FRONTEND CODE

```
function traerRegistrosDB(){

    fetch("/registros")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(()=>{
        console.error("registros innacesibles")
    })
};
```

ERROR
`http://localhost:3000/registros 404 (Not Found)`

-I tried doing a console.log() in the back. It didn't show up

-Adding headers

-Going directly to the direction local..../registros

Comment: `app.get("/registros",()=>{ ... });` - try with the leading `/`

Comment: have you tried through postman?, also try with explicitly telling it's a get a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a slash :
`app.get("registros"` should be  `app.get("/registros"`

Answer (score 0):

Since the backend and frontend addresses are different, you need to enter the full address when using fetch.

I am sharing the example below.
Suppose the backend address is http://localhost:8080.

```js
function traerRegistrosDB(){

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/registros")
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(()=>{
        console.error("registros innacesibles")
    })
};
```

Comment: Express isn’t listening in that route

Comment: At what address is the backend application running? @pierpy